# Are there any significant benefits of wrapping a double in NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a chunk of code that does some heavy math stuff based on how the class was configured. I'm currently using doubles everywhere I can internally since they offer more then enough precision for what I'm doing.

Originally, I wrote most of my methods to accept doubles as parameters wherever possible, mostly to keep the code clean. However, these same methods return NSNumber objects since I was using `nil` to check if the method actually returned a valid value or not (in some cases, the code can encounter a non-fatal error and return nil instead).

So my typical code looked like this:

```
MyMathClass *mathClass = [[MyMathClass alloc] init];

NSNumber *result = [mathClass doSomethingProfound:1234.0];

if (result == nil) {
    // handle failure gracefully
} else {
    NSLog(@"the number times 100 is %f", [result doubleValue] * 100);
}
```

However, I'm not entirely clear on why I'm bothering wrapping everything up in an NSNumber class for return. It seemed like a good idea at the time, but digging around in math.h has lead me to discover the NAN and isnan() macros, which I could probably use to return a double directly (without the intermediary NSNumber object) and detect success or failure accordingly.

So, instead, my code would look like this:

```
MyMathClass *mathClass = [[MyMathClass alloc] init];

double result = [mathClass doSomethingProfound:1234.0];

if (isnan(result)) {
    // handle failure gracefully
} else {
    NSLog(@"the number times 100 is %f", result * 100);
}
```

Apart from somewhat simplifying things and cutting down on the number of objects I'm flinging around, is there any serious downside to writing code like this that relies on NAN and isnan() to detect failures (rather then returning objects and checking for nil)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber` objects are not for doing maths at all, but for cases where you need to store a number as an object. For example the various collection classes; `NSArray`, `NSSet` *et al*; all manage collections of objects so you use `NSNumber` objects if you wish to put numbers into one of these collections.

For maths just use ordinary numeric data types; `double`, `int`, `CGFloat` (a framework defined alias for one of the basic floating-point types), *et al*. You are wasting memory, time, and possibly even precision (as type conversion can occur), using `NSNumber`.

HTH